# switch case substitute for inside a python 3.9 class

Tags: python-3.x, switch-statement

I have these methods in a class "driver":

- def act_left()
- def act_right()
- def act_straight()

When I call for init of that class I get an array of actions numbers between 0-2 and I translate these into the actions above.
I thought about using switch-case but I found out there is no such thing in python 3.9.
Do you know any elegant alternative, since I really has 10 of these actions and don't want to do a lot of else if's.

Thanks!

Comment: No since I need to activate a function in my object.

Comment: Maybe a list of functions: `actions = [act_left, act_right, act_straight]`. Then `for i in list_of_numbers: actions[i]()`.

Comment: Why can't you use a dictionary to replace a switch statement and still activate a function in your object?